# How to send a push notification to more than one device (iOS) in one request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I send  notification to users one by one and it takes a while.
This my code

```
var deviceios = db.Devices;

        int port = 2195;
        String hostname = "gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com";


        string certificatePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("mypath/cert.p12);

        string certificatePassword = "password";



        foreach (var item in deviceios)
        {


            X509Certificate2 clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
            X509Certificate2Collection certificatesCollection = new X509Certificate2Collection(clientCertificate);

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(hostname, port);
            SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(
                            client.GetStream(),
                            false,
                            new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
                            null
            );

            try
            {
                sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname, certificatesCollection, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Default, false);
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException ex)
            {
                client.Close();
                return;
            }

            //// Encode a test message into a byte array.
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);

            writer.Write((byte)0);  //The command
            writer.Write((byte)0);  //The first byte of the deviceId length (big-endian first byte)
            writer.Write((byte)32); //The deviceId length (big-endian second byte)
            string devicetocken = item.device1;//  iphone device token
            byte[] b0 = HexString2Bytes(devicetocken);
            WriteMultiLineByteArray(b0);

            writer.Write(b0);
            String payload;
            string strmsgbody = "";
            int totunreadmsg = 1;
            strmsgbody = message;
            payload = "{\"aps\":{\"alert\":\"" + strmsgbody + "\",\"badge\":" + totunreadmsg.ToString() + ",\"sound\":\"mailsent.wav\"},\"acme1\":\"bar\",\"acme2\":42}";
            writer.Write((byte)0); //First byte of payload length; (big-endian first byte)  
            byte[] b1 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
            writer.Write((byte)b1.Length);    //payload length (big-endian second byte)  
            writer.Write(b1);
            writer.Flush();
            byte[] array = memoryStream.ToArray();
            try
            {
                sslStream.Write(array);
                sslStream.Flush();
            }
            catch
            {



            }
            client.Close();
```

to send a notification to multiple devices i must send it to each device individually.  Can I send notifications to list of device?

Comment: Try using your own server. Next update, you put in a function that listens to a webserver, and when it fires some event, it states a push event.

Comment: Have you considered using ASP.Net SignalR by any chance? It is meant for that purpose.

Comment: Using own server doesn't change the way APN works. Also using SignalR is completely different from doing push notifications. As for the question, you aren't opening and closing the connection for every notification? That will take a long time. The notifications have to be sent one by one but they can be sent inside a single connection. You just have to handle error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using .NET for sending notifications, you can try to use Azure Notification Hub. There is an option to send template notifications, which allows you to send cross-platform notifications.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-aspnet-cross-platform-notification

Also, you can specify tag expressions, which allow you to send notifications to specific group of devices that are registered with targeted tags. I believe this could help you with sending notifications to multiple devices with one request. Combining this and using templates, you could even send notifications to multiple Android, Windows Phone and iOS devices with single request.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-tags-segment-push-message

You can find more about Azure Notification Hub here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-overview